# What's the best way to add space between mapped items in a column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I have created a simple list using the map function and I want to add some space between each of the items, currently I have used a Column as a wrapper and then added Sized box to create space between each item.

```
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: hobbies
                .map((hobby) => (Column(children: [
                      Text(hobby,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      )
                    ])))
                .toList(),
          ),
```

[image: The list I have made]

But it does not seem right to add columns inside a column and additionally the column are getting generated for nothing more than the purpose of wrapping the two items, I want to know if there is a better way to achieve the same results, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways like using `spaceBetween` property, adding `SizeBox`, and providing `Padding` and `margin`. One of the simplest is using `padding` in your case. like

```
(hobby)=> Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0) //or use bottom only,
        child: Text(hobby,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            )),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mainAxisAlignment of MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween OR MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround OR MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly on the Column for spacing.
On another note Column inside another Column is perfectly fine.
You can also use Wrap widget which can get a direction and then act like a Column or Row. The Wrap widget has spacing property you can read more about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

You can pick either of the 3 options. Let me know if you need anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mapping, you could use `fold` (Docs: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html)

Example:

```dart
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: hobbies
        .fold([], (arr, hobby) => [
              ...arr,
              Text(hobby,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              )
            ]),
),
```

This way you'll avoid nested columns, but still be able to use the SizedBox if that's exactly what you need.

Please consider you could wrap the text in a Padding too, instead of separating with SizedBox, and this would allow you to use `map` again.